# FileOpen, FileSave Confusion

Tags: wxpython

my program has two functions (amongst others): one to save a file and one to load a file:

```
def OnFileSave(self, event):
    mystring = ...
    f = file(os.path.join(dirName[0], fileName[0]), 'w')
    f.write(mystring)
    self.PushStatusText("Spiel gespeichert!")
    f.close()
    e.Skip()
    return True

def OnFileOpen(self, event):
    dlg = wxFileDialog(self, "Load File", dirName[0], fileName[0],
                       "MyFiles (*.mf)|*.mf|All Files|*.*", wx.OPEN)
    if (dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK):
        fileName[0] = dlg.GetFilename()
        dirName[0] = dlg.GetDirectory()
        f = file(os.path.join(dirName[0]+'\\', fileName[0]), 'r')
        ...
        dlg.Destroy()
```

both work as expected, but now I did a little change: when one file is already loaded (name != 'default') and I want to load another file, then the first file shall be saved before loading the other file. So I added only these two lines on top of my OnFileOpen(self,event):

```
if name != 'default':
    return self.OnFileSave(event)
```

Problem now: the first file gets successfully saved but the FileDialog doesn't open (so I can't load the other file). 
When I delete "return" in "return self.OnFileSave(event)" then the FileDialog opens and after choosing a file the FileDialog opens again. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not return. Just call something like:

```
if name != 'default':
    self.OnFileSave(None)
```

Comment: Thank you, after deleting e.skip() in OnFileSave() your answer works for me!